# PyTorch: Checking Model Accuracy Results in "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable."

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, attributeerror, pytorch-dataloader

I am training a neural network and would like to check its accuracy. I've used Librosa and SciKitLearn to represent audio in the form of 1D Numpy arrays. Thus `x_train, x_test, y_train,` and `y_test` are all 1D Numpy arrays with the x_* arrays containing floats and the y_* arrays containing strings corresponding to classes of data. For example:

```
x_train = [0.235, 1.101, 3.497]
y_train = ['happy', 'angry', 'neutral']
```

I've written a dictionary to represent these classes (strings) as integers:

```
emotions = {
'01' : 'neutral',
'02' : 'calm',
'03' : 'happy',
'04' : 'sad',
'05' : 'angry',
'06' : 'fearful',
'07' : 'disgust',
'08' : 'surprised'}

emotion_list = list(emotions.values())
```

Next I've defined a class to transform this data such that it can be passed to torch.utils.data.DataLoader():

```
class MakeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train):
        self.x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
        self.y_train = torch.FloatTensor([emotion_list.index(each) for each in y_train])
    def __len__(self):
        return self.x_train.shape[0]
    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        x = self.x_train[ind]
        y = emotion_list.index(y_train[ind])
        return x, y
```

I define a training set, testing set, batch size, and load the data:

```
train_set = MakeDataset(x_train, y_train)
test_set = MakeDataset(x_test, y_test)

batch_size = 512

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

I define the model, train, and test as follows:

```
class TwoLayerMLP(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_in, H, D_out):
        super(TwoLayerMLP, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H)
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out)

    def forward(self, x):
        h_relu = self.linear1(x).clamp(min=0)
        y_pred = self.linear2(h_relu)
        return y_pred


model = TwoLayerMLP(180, 90, 8)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

epochs = 5000

total_train = 0
correct_train = 0
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for batch_num, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        audio , label = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(audio.float())
        loss = criterion(outputs, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        predicted = torch.max(outputs.data,1)
        total_train += float(label.size(0))
        
        # Code runs with line below commented 
        # Else returns "TypeError: 'bool' object not iterable."
        correct_train += sum(predicted == label)
```

Note that this code has been updated, formerly the problematic line was:

```
correct_train += float((predicted == label)).sum()
```

Can anyone explain why this boolean object cannot be iterated as expected?

### SOLVED

Please see the comments in abhiskk's answer below, but for clarity and brevity the following changes solved the problem:

```
pred_values, pred_indices = torch.max(outputs.data,1)
total_train += float(label.size(0))
correct_train += (sum(pred_indices == label)).item()
```

Comment: can you share the exact error in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicted variable contains both values and indices, you need to do `pred_vals, pred_inds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)` and then you can do `correct_train += (sum(pred_inds == label)).item()`

Also you don't need to convert to float before summing, you can use:

`(predicted == label).sum().item()`

`(predicted == label)` returns a `BoolTensor` which can be summed to obtain a float value.

Comment: Using (predicted == label).sum().item() returns:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'

It seems as though the BoolTensor cannot be summed for some reason? Any debugging tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you check in your code what are the `predicted` and `label` tensors. I am guessing they are not tensors and there are other bugs in the code. 

Also I would re-iterate that there are a number of typos in the code you copy pasted in your question, I would double check to make sure that the reproduction code is runnable. If you can copy paste the minimal python file on maybe https://pastebin.com/ that would be very helpful. For eg, the code eg I pasted in my initial answer with tx, ty works quite well. Its behavior is similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: The `(predicted == label)` is returning a python `bool` for you which should not be happening if `predicted` and `label` are pytorch tensors. Either the code contains some other bug or you are on an old version of pytorch. 

Can you add reproducible code and also check pytorch version with `import torch; print(torch.__version__)`.

Comment: I've pasted the minimal python code at https://pastebin.com/Jtf8VVeh and confirmed it runs without error, assuming the (predicted == label) statement is commented out.  I've also printed predicted and label, and both print tensors. However, predicted technically prints a torch.return_types.max() object containing two tensors: 'values' and 'indices.'

Comment: Also, I am running PyTorch version 1.9.1+cu102

Comment: The output of printing 'predicted' and 'label' has been pasted at https://pastebin.com/f36rc07y

Comment: The `predicted` variable contains both values and indices, you need to do `pred_vals, pred_inds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)` and then you can do `correct_train += (sum(pred_inds == label)).item()`

Comment: For reference documentation of torch.max https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.max.html?highlight=torch%20max#torch.max

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to research this problem and provide a working solution with references.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
correct_train += float((predicted == label)).sum()
```

with

```
correct_train += sum(predicted == label)
```

You don't need to convert boolean tensor to float, the `sum` function is smart enough to convert False to 0 and True to 1

Comment: Replacing with correct_train += sum(predicted == label) returns a TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable.   I've printed (predicted == label) and it simply outputs False. Any debugging tips would be appreciated, thanks for your reply.